# Using SetWindowTheme() and pszSubIdList parameter

Tags: c#, listview, themes

I'm trying to apply Windows File Explorer visual style theme on a `ListView` and its `Header`. In my code, `ListView` is derived and `Header` is subclassed.

As we can see with [Theme Explorer](http://www.mctrl.org/tools.php), two different themes exist for `ListView/Header`: **Explorer** and **ItemsView**. The last one renders steel blue text header.

While I successfully themed `ListView` using `SetWindowTheme(Handle, "explorer", null)`, I'm unable to apply the **ItemsView** version.

I would like `Header` appears like this:

[image]

The following doesn't work (it renders regular **Explorer** theme): `SetWindowTheme(Handle, "itemsview", "header")`.

How could I apply this specific theme? Is it even possible?